# C programming-Divide number into digits and save them in list (array)

Tags: c

I want to divide number into digits and save them in a 5 element array with zeros on the left in C.For example if have a number  like 234 i want to make an array :[0 0 2 3 4].If i have a 4 digit number like 3486 :[0 3 4 8 6] and if i have a 5 digit number like 32894 [3 2 8 9 4]

Comment: i dont know what to do...i ll use to arrays with zeros like c[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}.Then go the number like 345.Use modulo %10 for the number store its integer and then put each integer to each element of the array from the right so that i get c[5] = {0, 0, 3, 4, 5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think your looking for something like this:

Here i'm using `%10` and `/10` so i can go trought the number digit by digit starting from the end of the number and as soon as the number is 0 i fill the rest of the array with 0's.

Little example of `%10` and `/10`:

```
Number: 123
        123 % 10 = 3  //last digit
Number: 123 / 10 = 12
        12  % 10 = 2  //second digit
Number: 12  / 10 = 1
        1   % 10 = 1  //first digit
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int number, count;
    int numbers[5];

    printf("Please enter a number:\n>");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for(count = 4; count >= 0; count--) {

        if(number <= 0)
            numbers[count] = 0;

        numbers[count] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;

    }

    for(count = 0; count < 5; count++)
        printf("%d", numbers[count]);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @Hmmas Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: added and explanation with a example! Also you accept answer's how helped you so people with the same problem find the answer faster!)

Comment: i dont have enough reputation...